# Under newly poured yard slab water leak

Tags: concrete

We just had a concrete slab poured yesterday for a new small hot tub. Concrete guys hit an irrigation pipe and it flooded the new slab less than 24 hours after poured. We realized this when our auto watering came in this morning. Hot tub being delivered tomorrow, to be placed on the new slab and weighs 400 lbs without water. We are in AZ and outside temp is about 70 degrees. Do you think this is a problem and should wait due to the weight (w/out water)?  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: "Concrete guys hit an irrigation pipe" Sounds like a call to the concrete guys to fix their mistake would be a good thing. They may have means to fix easier now, or tearing the slab up and starting again may be easier now.

Comment: Concrete is supposed to be kept damp for a few days, but they do not mean flood it.  Depending on the conditions the water came, good chance the concrete is ruined.

Comment: How many days between the pour and the hot tub arrival? Concrete needs time to cure to develop strength - it's easily damaged when newly poured. Not to mention the whole "so now you have a broken pipe under it that needs fixed" issue...

Comment: Not sure we know enough to declare the slab a write off, but while it’s a pain to find points A and B of the irrigation pipe at the edge of the new slab, a quick trench and U shaped extension pipe beside the slab will fix that. Just make sure it’s on the concrete guy’s dime.

Comment: My handy husband found and fixed the broken pipe…it obviously was hit with a pick axe.  Hot tub comes today (30 hours since flooding). Water on and surrounding slab has dissipated luckily but still concerned about the concrete slab integrity.

Comment: Glad your husband fixed it for you. Unfortunately, these concrete guys now get away with shoddy workmanship and you've just pushed the problem on to their next customers.

Comment: If not willing to repour a new slab, I would at least delay delivery by one week to allow extra curing time.